# Top Cohomology of $\mathbb{P}^2$ via Sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am trying to use the cohomology of the sphere to calculate $H^2(\mathbb{P}^2)$.

My professor just mentioned there's an argument using the projection $\pi: \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ and the antipodal map $\Phi$ on the sphere,and I want to see how it works. I have the deRham cohomology defined via forms.

I know that $\pi$ induces a map in cohomology $[\nu] \mapsto \pi^*[\nu] = [\pi^*\nu]$, and I want to show that $\pi*$ is an isomorphism, but don't see how.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: $H^2(\mathbb P^2; \mathbb R) = 0$.

Comment: Like Eric said, the top homology of $\mathbb P^2$ is zero, since even-dimensional Real projective spaces are not orientable. Maybe you can show that the orientation form in $\mathbb S^{2n}$ pulls back to the zero form under the projection: $\pi: S^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb P^{2n}$.

Comment: Actually, using cell homology, you can see that the top attaching maps have degree 0, so that the pullback of the top form in $S^{2n}$ is sent to the zero form.

Comment: The top cohomology class must vanish as $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$ is not orientable.

Comment: Thanks everyone; I've altered my statement, and I think I see how it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking at cohomology with real coefficients, so we can take deRham cohomology.

Here is a sketch why ${\text dim}H^n(\mathbb{P}^n)=1$ for $n$ odd,  $0$ for $n$ even.

1. Show that for any compact connected $n$-dim $M$, $H^n(M)=1$ if $M$ is orientable, $0$ if not.
2. Show that the antipodal map $\Phi:S^n\to S^n$ is orientation preserving for $n$ odd,  reversing  for $n$ even.
3. Deduce from 2 that $\Phi$ acts by the identity  on $H^n(S^n)$ for $n$ odd, by $-1$ for $n$ even.
4. For any form $\Omega$ on $\mathbb P^n$, let $\omega=\pi^*\Omega.$ Then $\Phi^*\omega=\omega$ (use  $\pi\circ\Phi=\pi$ and the chain rule).
5. Use the above as follows: for $n$ even, if ${\text dim}H^n(\mathbb{P}^n)=1$, then $\mathbb{P}^n$ is orientable, hence admits a volume form, i.e. a non-vanishing $n$-form $\Omega$. But then $\omega=\pi^*\Omega$ would be a volume form on $S^n$ (since $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism) and $\Phi$ invariant (by 4). But then its deRham cohomology class would be non-trivial (since it is nonvanishing) and also $\Phi$-invariant, contradicting 3.
6. For $n$ odd, the standard volume form on $S^n$ is $\Phi$-invariant, hence descends to a volume form on $\mathbb{P}^n$, thus $\mathbb{P}^n$ is orientable, so  ${\text dim}H^n(\mathbb{P}^n)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this shows that the top homology of $\mathbb P^{2n}$ is zero, using cell homology, and degrees of the boundary maps. Any continuous map $f: X \rightarrow Y$  (assuming $X,Y$ compact, like in our case, to avoid problems with integration)gives you a contravariant map in cohomology. In particular, for any volume form $w$ in $H^n(Y; \mathbb R)$ , you get $$d\int_Xf^{*}w=\int_Y w$$ , where d is the degree of $f$ (the top attaching map), and $f^{*}w$ is the pullback of $w$ under $f$. For even-dimensional projective spaces, $d=0$, so the top form $w$ pullsback to a zero form on $X$ , (it must be a zero form, since a volume form cannot integrate to $0$ over the whole space). It may need some changes, but I think it is essentially correct.

Comment: The direction you're headed — including the definition of degree — only makes sense for *orientable* manifolds.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: True; but I was working with the attaching map between n-cells (both orientable), trying to finagle a proof of the nonorientability of $\mathbb P^2$

Answer (score 0):

I think it suffice to use the long exact sequence in cohomology.

$$0=H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^{2})\rightarrow H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^{1})\rightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{P}^{2},\mathbb{P}^{1})\rightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{P}^{2})\rightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{P}^{1})=0$$

The first map is  the $0$ map. The second map is the $\times 2$ coboundary map. The third map is the quotient map. The last map is the zero map. So you conclude that

$$H^{2}(\mathbb{P}^{2})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$

and I think a similar strategy can be used to compute the cohomology ring of $\mathbb{RP}^{n}$ by induction.